# How to add my own extensions to a spree application and deploy it to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, spree

I followed https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html and completed the extension spree_simple_sales. Everything is working fine in development. But I can't figure out how to deploy it.

When I run

```
rails g spree_simple_seals:install
```

it gives me

```
append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js
append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js
insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css
run  bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations   FROM=spree_simple_sales from "."
Would you like to run the migrations now? [Y/n] y
run  bundle exec rake db:migrate from "."
```

None of the other added codes seem to be copied in. But somehow the application is running correctly. How does this work?

Then I tried to deploy it to heroku. But, unsuprisingly, there is this error:

```
The path `/tmp/spree_extensions/spree_simple_sales` does not exist.
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Here is the Gemfile. The last is the spree_simple_sales extension, with a path to a local directory, as instructed by the tutorial:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'puma'
end

gem 'spree', '3.0.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_simple_sales', path: '../spree_extensions/spree_simple_sales'
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile please?

Comment: I just added the Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Just put the extension directory under /vendor and reference it from the Gemfile and it'll work on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.  by querying the spree community i discovered the right way to add a custom extensions is to give it its own git repo and then reference that git repo in the gem file.

gem 'spree_simple_sales', github: 'username/spree_simple_sales'